# find mysql databases/tables, which are stored in innodb engine

Tags: mysql, innodb

How to find mysql databases/tables, which are stored in innodb engine?

Show tables just list the tables but not tell which are innodb and which are myisam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
SELECT ENGINE
FROM information_schema.TABLES
```